# First order ODE: $ (x-2y^2)dx + (2xy)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the ODE

$$(x-y^2)dx + (2xy)dy =0$$

**My attempt:**

If

$$M(x,y)=x-y^2 \text{ and } N(x,y)=2xy$$

then,

$$M'_y = -2y \text{ and } N'_x=2y$$

Since

$$\frac{M'_y - N'_x}{N}=\frac{-2y -2y}{2xy} = \frac{-2}{x}$$

only deppends on x, I thought that it should be an integrant factor. But it is not working.

What I did wrong? What should I do, in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: The integrating factor is not supposed to be $x\mapsto -\dfrac 2 x$, but rather $x\mapsto \exp\left(\displaystyle \int -\dfrac 2 x\mathrm dx\right)$, where $x\mapsto {\displaystyle \int -\dfrac 2 x\mathrm dx}$ denotes any antiderivative of $x\mapsto  -\dfrac 2x$. Things simplify nicely.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential equation is:

$$(x-y^2) + (2xy)y' =0$$

Using integrating factors, we have that:

$$M = x-y^2,\ N = 2xy$$

Taking the partials:

$$M_y = -2y,\ N_x = 2y$$

Since they are not exact, we must find an integrating to make them exact:

$$\frac{M_y-N_x}{N} = \frac{-2}{x}$$

The integrating factor, then is:

$$e^{\int \frac{-2}{x}} = e^{-2\ln{x}} = x^{-2}$$

Multiply this integrating factor in your original ODE and repeat this method. Since $M_y$ and $N_x$ are exact now, you can use the theorem of exactness to find the solution to the ODE.